# pointer aliasing

Tags: pointers, pointer-aliasing

what is the difference between **"Strict"**, **"Typed"**, **"Restricted"** and **"Disjointed"** aliasing?

Comment: i found http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/restrict.html#restricted-pointers for "Restricted Pointer"

Comment: http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7598/bjafc?a=view

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **"Strict aliasing**", pointers don't alias if they are different types.
In **"Typed aliasing"**, pointers of the same type can alias and overlap.
In **"Restricted aliasing"**, pointers of same type are assumed to not overlap.
In **"Disjointed aliasing"**, all pointer expressions result in no overlap.